# create a file outside the directory in PHP

Tags: php

I wanted to create a file outside the recent directory

The script is running here:

```
  WWW/PHP/USERS/__createfile.php
```

And I want to create file using move_uploaded_file() in this directory:

```
  WWW/FILE/
```

Any workaround here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `move_uploaded_file()` you can place a file wherever you want so long as you have the correct permissions.

Just use `../` to go back a directory from where you are.

So to go back a directory from where you are and place a `png` file there, do

```
move_uploaded_file($filename, dirname(__FILE__).'/../myfile.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should  be able to just pass any path that the script has access to on the server.

```
<?php
move_uploaded_file($filename, 'WWW/FILE/newfile.ext');
?>
```

Remember that whatever you're passing must be a directory, not a web path

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests, [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) is for moving the uploaded file. You cannot use that function to create new files.

You can, however, use [`fopen()`](http://php.net/fopen) for that purpose.

**An example:**

```
$filename = "../path/to/file/which/is/to/be/created.php";
$handle = fopen($filename, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fclose($handle);
```